# Automatically running unit tests in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there a way to run my test suites with my build command? All I can find is that I can run e.g. `cabal test` after `cabal build`. What I want is a way to automatically run my tests when running e.g. `cabal build`.

I want a solution that will automate this for anyone building the package without requiring them to run a different script. An analogy would be a java build script where the default build target runs unit tests after compiling.

Comment: With [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) you may do like [`stack test`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_command/)

Comment: @Redu with Cabal you may do like `cabal test`, for the purpose of this question there's no difference between Stack and Cabal.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to impose the computational cost of running your tests on anybody building your package? This seems to be an XY problem, what you're actually looking for is a good continuous integration framework.

Comment: @leftaroundabout what is the point of having unit tests if you don't run them whenever you make a code change? Running them as part of a build is common in Java and other languages. Re: computational cost: yes, unit tests should run fast; this is an orthogonal issue.

Comment: Of course you run the tests whenever you make a code change (with `cabal test`, or you have the CI do it for you), but most people who build the package will _not_ have made any changes to the code.

Comment: @leftaroundabout "most people who build the package will not have made any changes." That is false. Besides, even if I was distributing open source software, I could still build using a different target during development than the one I would instruct end users to use.

Comment: @jsbg exactly, you _should_ build using a different target during development than the one you would instruct end users to use. Namely, with `cabal test`, whereas everybody else would use only `cabal build` or `cabal install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `cabal.project.local` to do this when using cabal v2 projects (as in, `cabal v2-build` which is the default and thus the same as `cabal build` for cabal version 3.0 and up).

The strategy is just to place a `cabal.project.local` file in the build directory with contents of:

```
tests: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this a really bad idea since it's unexpected, non-canonical behavior that breaks cross-compilation, but you can probably hack it together with a `Custom` build type.

Here's an example `mypackage.cabal`:

```
cabal-version:       >=2.0
name:                mypackage
version:             0.1.0.0
author:              None
maintainer:          none@example.com
build-type:          Custom

custom-setup
  setup-depends:
    base  >= 4.5,
    Cabal >= 2.0

executable mypackage
  main-is: Main.hs
  build-depends: base >= 4
  default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite test
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  build-depends: base >= 4
  main-is: Test.hs
```

and a corresponding `Setup.hs`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Distribution.Simple
import Distribution.Simple.Setup
import Distribution.Simple.Test
import Distribution.Simple.Build

main = defaultMainWithHooks simpleUserHooks {
  postBuild = myPostBuild
}

myPostBuild args flags desc info =
  when ("exe:mypackage" `elem` buildArgs flags) $ do
    build desc info defaultBuildFlags { buildDistPref = buildDistPref flags } []
    test ["test"] desc info defaultTestFlags {
      testDistPref = buildDistPref flags
    }
```

This does result in a project where `cabal build` also builds and runs the tests on my Cabal 3.0.0.0 system, but I don't know which additional caveats this has.

Comment: Can you explain why it breaks cross-compilation?

Comment: @jsbg Building and running a test suite will fail when cross-compiling because the compiled output can't be executed on the host system. Cabal doesn't support distinguishing between a host and cross compiler afaik.

Comment: Thanks, I don't care about cross-compilation (not distributing the source) so this is fine.